# What can we do for efficiency using omp critical in the situation that omp atomic/reduction cannot be applied?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm facing one problem in c++.

Suppose we have `vector<SomeClass> v` and we want to add all the elements of `v` using multithreading. (the size of `v` is `N`.)
We have a overload of `+=` operator in `SomeClass` but that is not atomic-compatible.

```
SomeClass sum; // init by "zero" but not exactly a single (int)
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
   #pragma omp critical
   {
      sum += v[i];
   }
}
```

My experiment shows that the running time of this code is similar to the one with single thread.
I think this is due to the `critcial` section where only one thread is allowed to evaluate addition at a time. (I canoot take advantage of multithread).
Alternative would be use of `atomic` or (`reduction`), but they are not available because `+=` is not for atomic variables.

In this case, what can we do?
Should I quit to use multithread here?
Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you mean with "not atomic-compatible" ? `std::atomic<T>` is fine with any TriviallyCopyable `T` and it does have a `operator+=`

Comment: btw your problem as written is inherently sequential. Either you split the vector to compute sub-sums (and add them later) or you wont gain anything from using more than one thread

Comment: Look into OpenMP `reduction`, this is **exactly** the kind of thing it is intended to deal with, assuming your addition is commutative. If not, there are sometimes other things one can do, but we'd need to know a few more details in order to assist further in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a reduction. If the class is not supported by the standard `reduction(op:var)` directive of openMP, you can don it manually.

Each threads sums vector values into a private accumulator. Then, the private accumulator are summed into a global one (which has to be done only once per thread for the whole loop, rather that at each iteration)

```
SomeClass sum; // init by "zero" but not exactly a single (int)
#pragma omp parallel
{
    SomeClass mySum=0; //local accumulator, init with 0 or whatever the "zero" is for that class
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) mySum += v[i];

    #pragma omp critical
    sum += mySum; //The critical section is entered only once
}
```

Comment: Any other hopes for implementing method not using `critical`?

Comment: You can't do a reduction without at least one `critical` or `atomic` step when merging the results from the various threads. This implementation moves the `critical` section out of the loop, so performance should not be much affected while benefiting from loop parallelism. You may use the user defined `define  reduction` from @Tom Scogland's answer; there will still be an implicit critical section hidden within.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent reply. Btw, is zero initialization of  local accumulator necessary? I found that if I write `SomeClass mySum;` not `SomeClass mySum=0;` the program does not provide correct result of the `sum`.

Comment: Each thread will create a local variable mySum, so you need to initiaize it with a neutral value consistent with the operation being done (e.g. for a sum, 0; for a multiplication, 1; to seek a minimum, some very large value, etc). Basically, if you remove the for loop and just code  `SomeClass mySum=0; sum += mySum;` then the value of `sum` should not be affected.

Answer (score 2):

@Brice's answer is right in that you want a reduction, but for something where `+=` is the operator you want, you should be able to use OpenMP reduction natively.  Even if it's not, the specification offers user-defined reductions to allow reductions over arbitrary types with arbitrary expressions, for example:

```
// For a version that uses a `.combine()` method
// #pragma omp declare reduction(somered:SomeClass: omp_out.combine(omp_in))
#pragma omp declare reduction(somered:SomeClass: omp_out += omp_in)
// this assumes you can initialize with SomeClass tmp = 0;
// if not, add initializer() clause with a correct initialization for the tmp
SomeClass sum; // init by "zero" but not exactly a single (int)
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(somered: sum)
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
      sum += v[i];
}
```

Comment: Good point. The intent of doing a reduction is made clear to the compiler (and to whoever is reading the code), the code is more compact and cleaner.